# Get data from shown plot in matplotlib and pass it to a probability density function

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have a plot in matplotlib created from an array of data. I have added a button labeled 'PD'. How do I get data from the plot and pass it to a probability density function when the button is clicked?
I've tried going through the documentation but it's not that clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using the `gca` method in `matplotlib` to retrieve the data from an active plot.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(0, 100, 100)

y1 = x**2

plt.plot(x, y1)


line = plt.gca().get_lines()
x_data = lines[0].get_data()[0]
y1_data = lines[0].get_data()[1]
```

Comment: I'm getting index out of range at the line  x_data = lines[0].get_data()[0]

Comment: Try to `print(lines[0].get_data())` just to see the shape of the data.

Comment: Seemed to have been my mistake. I was getting trying to get the axes of subplot which had no values. Thanks alot. Your solution worked

Comment: Glad I could help!

Comment: @Michael could you elaborate on your last comment? I am still stuck at the point where I'm getting "list index our of range"

Answer (score -1):

You could try using this:

```
    lines = ax.get_lines()
    for line in lines:
        xd = line.get_xdata()
        yd = line.get_ydata()
```